# Is "ŝien" a meaningful word?

Tags: word-usage

I'm reading Orwell's 1984 in Donald Broadribb's translation, as [found online](https://lernu.net/eo/forumo/temo/17762). I found this strange word in this sentence in page 82:

> Sed nepre ŝi vidis lin marŝanta **ŝien**, kaj eble ŝi akceptos tiun
>   sugeston.

While the meaning is intuitively clear – surely they mean the same as "ŝiadirekten" earlier in the same page, as confirmed by the [English version](http://www.george-orwell.org/1984/8.html)

> But she must have seen him coming towards her, and perhaps she would take the hint.

the composition of the word just feels unfounded to me. Though I am aware the translation has some typos (incidentally, I am quite sure "marŝanta" should have had an -n in the very same sentence, for example), this is different as it really sounds intentional.

Is this right? I found a related question discussed in [lernu](https://lernu.net/eo/forumo/temo/18194) but with no conclusive / authoritative resolution.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting.  I think I understand.  It is a rather strange usage, especially for English speakers.

"ŝie"- using ŝi as an adverb and then adding an "n" to become "ŝien" that denotes towards.  You also have a compound declension, which often occurs in Esperanto.

In this case, "ŝien" is being used to translate "Towards her" as an adverbial phrase.  Seeing "she" used as an adverb is a strange construct for an English speaker, since there is no word in English like "sheingly", but I don't see why you couldn't make use of the extensible grammar in Esperanto as is done in this case.

Comment: I agree with your argument but fail to understand how "ŝi" could be a direct object of "marŝanta", more so as the verb "marŝi" is intransitive according to [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#mar%C5%9Di) and [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/marsx.html#marsx.0i).

Comment: I see what you mean that marŝanta is indeed an intranstive verb.  I removed a portion of my answer that stated that you could use ŝin as a direct object.

Answer (score 4):

About `marŝanta` without accusative `-n`.

```
ŝi vidis lin marŝanta ŝien
```

Compare this with the correct

```
li opinias ŝin plej bela.
```

(She not necessarily *is* most beautiful.)

So accusative is indeed not needed. `-anta` is used to hint at a duration instead of `marŝi` for instance.

`ŝien` instead of `al ŝi` for *towards* is also creatively correct.

It still is simple fluent language, and very finely translates the nuances of the original, though three statistical artefacts are a bit much.

More "natural" translations are feasible both from English to other languages, as also to Esperanto. Neither English nor Esperanto have a special quality in this respect.

> But she must have seen him coming towards her, and perhaps she would take the hint.
>
> Tamen lia alproksimiĝo (al ŝi) estis tute klara (evidenta), kaj eble ŝi akceptus la sugeston.

`take the hint` has better translations, but there might be some context for the choice made.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for also considering the other comment of mine! In my head I compared this sentence with the popular "Mi pentris la domon verdan" / "Mi pentris la domon verda". In this manner I would say ŝi actually did see lin marŝanta**n**, but I can see how "marŝanta" would be acceptable (with a subtle difference in meaning, but with no risk of misunderstanding as in the case of pentri).